# Problem with CodeIgniter. DX_Auth not working when deployed

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-datamapper

So we're currently using CodeIgniter + DataMapper OverZealous Edition + DX Auth.  It is working on our local machines, as well as our staging server.  As soon as we push to their server though, the login doesn't work at all.  Upon further investigation, the data from the form is not coming in to the controller where we do our authentication.  We've killed all the server side CI data validation and it still comes in blank.

Our staging server is running:

Server  Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5.2 mod_wsgi/2.3 PHP/5.2.6-2ubuntu4.5 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.6-2ubuntu4.5

Their server is running:

Server  Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.9

I really don't want to have to put in a different authentication framework in the 11th hour, I've already pulled too many all nighters for this project.  Anyone have any ideas???

Comment: Do both print_r($_POST) and print_r($_REQUEST) show empty arrays, or ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was something the client put in the htaccess.  They have removed it and it is now all working.

BTW, $_POST was an empty array and $_REQUEST didn't show any post data, but would show get data.  I think it was the post_max_size directive they set.  I guess this won't work in htaccess, because I know they would have set it to 45M or so, and we were testing on a form with one text field, so we were no where close to that max.